# OCaml Adding Natural Numbers

Tags: function, ocaml

I'm learning OCaml in school and recently came came across a program for an assignment that I couldn't understand, and was hoping if somebody could explain it to me. Here's the code:

```
(* Natural numbers can be defined as follows:
   type = ZERO | SUCC of nat;;

   For instance, two = SUCC (SUCC ZERO) and three = SUCC (SUCC (SUCC ZERO)).

  Write a function 'natadd' that adds two natural numbers in this fashion. *)

# type = ZERO | SUCC of nat;;
# let two = SUCC (SUCC ZERO);;
# let three = SUCC (SUCC (SUCC ZERO));;
# let rec natadd : nat -> nat -> nat =
    fun n1 n2 ->
      match n1 with
      | ZERO -> n2
      | SUCC n1 -> SUCC (natadd n1 n2)
  ;;
```

Here's a sample output for the code:

```
# natadd two three;;
- : nat = SUCC (SUCC (SUCC (SUCC (SUCC ZERO))))
```

What I don't understand is the match-with statement. Does it mean that if n1 is non-zero, then it adds SUCC and uses [SUCC n1] as a new argument in place of n1 for the recursive call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't use `SUCC n1` as the argument of the recursive call, it uses only `n1` (the part of the matched `SUCC`) as the argument. The `SUCC` is then applied to the result of the recursive call.

The code might be a bit confusing because there are two variables with the name `n1`. Better might be

```
let rec natadd : nat -> nat -> nat = fun a b ->
  match a with
  | ZERO -> b
  | SUCC a_pred -> SUCC (natadd a_pred b)
```

Comment: Thank you! One other thing that I was wondering is, how does the recursive function know when to stop?

Comment: @Sean It stops when it reaches `ZERO`, in that case it won't call itself again

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know what you mean when you say that it may be confusing, as the scoping issue also comes into play. I've learned something today.